# Pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)=nx^n(1-x)$ on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

If there is an easier way to see this I would be thrilled to know that way. I think the trick is to make sure the maximum of $f_n$ occurs to the right of a fixed $x_0$ so that we can avoid the function converging to $\frac{1}{e}$.

**Attempt.**

For x=1 and x=0, $f_n(x)=0$. Fix an $x_0\in(0,1)$. Since the max of each $f_n$ occurs at $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$, choose $N_1$ such that $n>N$ imples $\frac{n}{n+1} >x_0$. Then for $n>N, \exists \delta>0$ such that $\frac{n}{n+1}-\delta>x_0$.

So $|f_n(x_0)|=|nx_0^n(1-x_0)|\leq |n(\frac{n}{n+1}-\delta)^n(1-(\frac{n}{n+1}-\delta))| = |n(\frac{n}{n+1}-\delta)^n(\frac{1}{n+1}+\delta)|$

Now,
$|n(\frac{n}{n+1}-\delta)^n(\frac{1}{n+1}+\delta)| \leq |n(\frac{n}{n+1}-\delta)^n(\frac{1}{n+1})| = |\frac{n}{n+1}(\frac{n}{n+1}-\delta)^n|$

and since $\frac{n}{n+1} \leq 1$, $|f_n(x_0)| \leq (\frac{n}{n+1}-\delta)^n = (1-(\frac{1}{n+1}+\delta))^n \leq (1-\delta)^n$

So given an $\epsilon>0$, choose $n>\frac{log(\epsilon)}{log(1-\delta)}$

Comment: Maybe consider f_n+1{x}/f_n(x)

Answer (score 2):

Fix $x \in (0,1)$.  It suffices to prove that 
$$
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (n x^n) = 0.
$$
We have
$$
\tag{$*$}
\frac{(n+1) x^{n+1}}{n x^n} = \Bigl( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \Bigr) x,
$$
which is $< 1$ for $n > x/(1-x)$.  Consequently, the sequence $(n x^n)$, being eventually decreasing and bounded below (by $0$), converges to some $a \in [0, 1)$.  But $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} ((n + 1) x^{n+1}) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (n x^{n}) = a$, so it follows from $(*)$ that $a = a x$, which is possible only if $a = 0$.

Comment: So for each fixed $x\in(0,1)$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^n$ converges by the ratio test and that implies $\lim nx^n =0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but it is a different way of proof.

Answer (score 0):

$nx^n(1-x)\leq nx^n$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ 
  $x^n=\frac{1}{(1+y)^n}$ for some $y\gt 1$

$(1+y)^n \ge \frac{n(n-1)}{2}y^2$  We  get $nx^n\le n\frac{2}{n(n-1)y^2}=\frac{2}{(n-1)y^2}$

You can continue from here